# Proof that $\operatorname{ker}(A^{T}A) = \operatorname{ker}(A)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a proof that can help me understand why this is the case? I can't conceptualize the reason for this in my mind. Thanks.

Comment: It's a double inclusion, can you prove any?

Comment: All of the things I have tried have been using definitions for $n\times n$ matrix $A$. But I am struggling to prove it for a non-square matrix.

Comment: What's your definition of the kernel of a matrix? Knowing that ought to help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For

$\vec v \in \ker A \tag{1}$

we have

$A \vec v = 0, \tag{2}$

whence

$A^TA \vec v = 0, \tag{3}$

showing that $\vec v \in \ker A^TA$; thus $\ker A \subset \ker A^TA$.  To go the other way, note that

$A^TA \vec v = 0 \tag{4}$

implies that

$\vec v^T A^TA \vec v = 0, \tag{5}$

or

$(A \vec v)^T(A \vec v) = 0; \tag{6}$

but $(A \vec v)^T(A \vec v)$ is a scalar quantity which if written out in terms of components is

$0 = (A \vec v)^T(A \vec v) = \sum (A \vec v)_i^2, \tag{7}$

where $(A \vec v)_i$ is the $i$-th component of $A\vec v$.  Thus we must have

$(A \vec v)_i = 0 \tag{7}$

for each and every $i$, implying

$A \vec v = 0 \tag{8}$

or

$\vec v \in \ker A, \tag{9}$

as desired.  ***QED.***

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  Try using $A^{T}Ax=0\implies x^{T}A^{T}Ax=0\implies (Ax)\cdot(Ax)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$S:=\text{ker}(A^TA) = \{\textbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n : (A^TA)\textbf{x} = 0 \}$$
$$S':=\text{ker}(A) = \{\text{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n: A\textbf{x} =0 \}$$

$(1) \ \ S' \subset S$: This is fairly easy since, $A\textbf{x} = 0 \Rightarrow A^TAx =A^T\cdot0 =0$

$(2)$ Can you show $S \subset S'$?

Answer (score 1):

The key is showing that if $A^T Ax = 0$, then $Ax = 0$.  There is a geometric interpretation to this statement.  Consider the vector $Ax$.  Since it is a linear combination of the columns of $A$, it clearly belongs to the column space of $A$.  And since $A^T (Ax) = 0$, $Ax$ belongs to the nullspace (kernel) of $A^T$.  But the column space of $A$ (also known as the row space of $A^T$) and the nullspace (kernel) of $A^T$ are orthogonal complements, and so in particular, the only vector that belongs to both subspaces is $0$.  Therefore, $Ax = 0$.